# How to modify a site element with chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-chrome-extension

I want to modify the content of a site with an extension, there are `<ul>` and `<il>` tags, (inside a `<div>`) and I want to add another `<il>` element inside the `<ul>`. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [inject JS into a site with a Chrome extension](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html). Using, for example, jQuery, you could do something along the lines of:

```
$("div > ul").append("<li>This is a new list element.</li>");
```

Which will append the "new list element" to the `ul` element.

Updated 2013.02.06:

Taken from the [Chrome extensions documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html). The manifest file would contain something along the lines of the following (where "..." indicates an omission):

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.the-site-your-targeting.com/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "myscript.js"]
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

And `myscript.js` would contain something along the lines of:

```
(function () {
    // $("#theIdOfTheElement").append("<li>Foo bar baz</li>");
    // OR
    // $(".aSpecificClassName").append("<li>Foo bar baz</li>");
}())
```

Read the [Getting Started](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html) article on the Chrome Developers site for more in-depth information on how the whole process of creating an extension works.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work. Should I have to declare the use of Jquery somewhere?. If the <ul> it's inside 5 <div> tags, how should I write it: $("div > div > .... ul")?

Comment: The code snippet is an example of what it'd look like. You'd need to find which element you want to target, and replace `"div > ul"` with a more specific selector.

Answer (score 0):

Without jQuery:

```
var ul = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
var newElement = document.createElement("li");
var textNode = document.createTextNode("New Element");
newElement.appendChild(textNode);
ul.appendChild(newElement);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! should I reach the <ul> through getElementsByTagName much times as I have elements in the way?

Comment: add attribute `id` to your element, for example `<ul id="myElement"/>` and get this element by function `var ul = document.getElementById("myElement");`

Comment: thank you very much! I will implement this in other projects, but the jquery method looks much simple. thanks! :)